# GAE: what are the args of webapp.RequestHanderls get(*args)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I read the document

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requesthandlerclass.html

but I cant find any information of the args parameters

Comment: Why don't you print the args that is passed to get and also find the type() of each of those arguments passed? This will definitely provide you a lot of answer till some one can point you to document that provides that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on the regular expressions in your URL matching. For example:

```
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
         ('/rechnungsdatencontainer/([a-z0-9_-]+)', RechnungsdatencontainerHandler),
         ('/empfaenger/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/rechnungen/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)\.?(json|pdf|xml|invoic|html)?', RechnungslisteHandler),
         ('/admin/credentials', CredentialsHandler),
         ('/', Homepage)],
        debug=True)
    util.run_wsgi_app(application)
```

`RechnungsdatencontainerHandler.get()` sees one parameter, `RechnungslisteHandler().get()` sees three and `CredentialsHandler` and `Homepage` get no parameters.

```
class RechnungsdatencontainerHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(containerid):
        ....

class RechnungslisteHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(empfaenger, rechung, fmt):
        ....
```

Basically every pair of (braces) in the RegExp results in a get parameter.

I *assume* you could also use named parameters, something like `(?P<kundennr>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)` to get `kwargs` in your get function, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Just for reference, this is in the docs: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running.html.

Comment: The first parameter in each "get" method should still have a "self" reference - other than that it looks good